# QueryBuilder ormlite is giving the wrong result

Tags: android, sql, nested, ormlite, query-builder

Have a created an activity that supports the SEARCH functions with multiple combination options for users to choose. Hence,users select a certain options within the Combination search field, the correct parameter should be pass through the show the correct result lists.

However, the search results are wrong. I am actually utilising a QueryBuilder: using the 'AND' and 'OR' logic. What I have realised is that in the log, the sequence of the 'AND' and 'OR' is mixed up. The following log is shown:

> 02-06 17:29:15.891: I/--------------------PropertySearchActivity--------------------(31850): SELECT * FROM `property` WHERE (((((`propertyCity` LIKE 'China' OR `propertyCountry` LIKE 'China' ) AND `propertyName` LIKE '%%' ) AND `propertyType` LIKE 'Office' ) OR `propertyType2` LIKE 'Office' OR `propertyType3` LIKE 'Office' ) AND `propertyVisibility` = 'Published' ) ORDER BY `propertyName`

As seen in the log, there are multiple '(' after 'WHERE', before 'propertyCity', secondly, I need an '(' in front of the OR statements such that the correct log should be:

> 02-06 17:29:15.891: I/--------------------PropertySearchActivity--------------------(31850): SELECT * FROM `property` WHERE (`propertyCity` LIKE 'China' OR `propertyCountry` LIKE 'China' ) AND `propertyName` LIKE '%%'  AND **(**`propertyType` LIKE 'Office'  OR `propertyType2` LIKE 'Office' OR `propertyType3` LIKE 'Office' **)** AND `propertyVisibility` = 'Published' ORDER BY `propertyName`

I have attached the following code for your perusal, pls assist. Thank You.

```
try {
        List<DbClassProperty> ls;
        QueryBuilder<DbClassProperty, Integer> qb = ((RootActivity) getContext())
                .getHelper().getDbClassPropertyDao().queryBuilder();

        qb.orderBy("propertyName", true);

        Where<DbClassProperty, Integer> wb = ((RootActivity) getContext())
                .getHelper().getDbClassPropertyDao().queryBuilder().where();

        if (countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Country.City"){


            wb.and(
                    wb.or (
                    wb.like("propertyCity", countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString()),
                    wb.like("propertyCountry", countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    ),

                    (wb.like("propertyName","%" + nameEdit.getText().toString() + "%")
                    )
                );
        }else

            wb.like("propertyName", "%" + nameEdit.getText().toString()+ "%");

        if (typeSpin.getSelectedItem().toString() != " Type") {

            wb.and()
                    .or(

                    wb.like("propertyType", typeSpin.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString()),
                    wb.like("propertyType2", typeSpin.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString()),
                    wb.like("propertyType3", typeSpin.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString())
                    );
        }

        wb.and().eq("propertyVisibility", "Published");
```

Comment: Uh, you can't use `==` and `!=` with strings. You need to use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if (countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Country.City"){


            wb.and(
                    wb.or (
                    wb.like("propertyCity", countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString()),
                    wb.like("propertyCountry", countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    ),

                    (wb.like("propertyName","%" + nameEdit.getText().toString() + "%")
                    )
                );
        }else

            wb.like("propertyName", "%" + nameEdit.getText().toString()+ "%");

        if (typeSpin.getSelectedItem().toString() != " Type") {
            wb.and(
                    wb.or (
                            wb.like("propertyType", typeSpin.getSelectedItem()
                                    .toString()),
                            wb.like("propertyType2", typeSpin.getSelectedItem()
                                    .toString()),
                            wb.like("propertyType3", typeSpin.getSelectedItem()
                                    .toString())
                    ),
                    wb.and().eq("propertyVisibility", "Published")
                );
        }
```

Comment: Uh, you can't use `==` and `!=` with strings.  You need to use `.equals()`.

Comment: @Gray   What is the alternative for !=?

Comment: `! .equals()` so something like `! typeSpin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Type")`

Comment: @Gray   I think !.equals() is a syntax error isn't it?? I don't think there is such a syntax available. But I do get your meaning

Comment: Sigh.  I mean (of course)  `! string.equals("foo")`.  I gave it to you right afterwards in my previous comment. Check your java manual.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't use `==` and `!=` to see if a `String` has the same contents of another `String`, you should use `equals(...)` method.  The only way a `String` is `==` to another `String` is if they are the same object.

But there does seem to be a bug here in ORMLite.  As I boil down your query, you are doing:

```
and(or(1, 2), 3)
and().or(4, 5, 6);
and().7
```

It's very strange to combine the "in-fix" query forms (`and()`) with the argument query forms (`or(1 ,2)`).  The in-fix `and()` is popping off the first `or(4)` when you'd expect it to treat the `or(4, 5, 6)` as a single entity.

I'll see how easy this is to fix in ORMLite.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean something like 'if (countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString() .equals("Country.City") )' instead of ' if (countrySpin.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Country.City")'??

Comment: it is actually more of ( ( (1 OR 2 OR 3)AND (4) ) AND  ( (5 OR 6 OR 7)AND (8) ) ), so there are 2 main parameters that need to be fulfilled